# Is there any way to check what gulp version you have installed?

Tags: html, json, git, gulp

Is there any way to check what gulp version you have installed and also what version of gulp is being offered by the website? I've searched online, and looked at the gulp website, but cannot find the version I need to put in my JSON file.

Comment: you can use gulp --version from the developer command prompt and this should give you the version

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Simply use: `gulp -v`

From the docs:

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/CLI.md

Comment: How do you find out what the latest version of gulp is? [Their site](http://gulpjs.com/) doesn't make this easy!

Comment: What context do I need to be in to run that command? From a Windows command prompt, I just get the `'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` error. I'm in the same directory as the gulp file.

Answer (score 20):

**`gulp -v` will not work if you don't have gulp-cli installed** (you will get the error `'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`).

**So 2 options:**

1. First run `npm -g install gulp-cli` then run `gulp -v`
2. Alternatively, you can just run `npm list gulp`

Comment: You need to `npm -g install gulp-cli` in order to use `gulp` from the command line.